# My updated ios app just shows splash screen after updating on existing one

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

We have release our new build day before yesterday and when users updated new app on old app, after successfully installed it was just showing updated splash screen and nothing else. Its not moving further from splash screen.

When i have checked this scenario in development mode by updating new app over old app, its working fine. But i am not aware of this issue after app goes live. So anyone can have idea about how to resolve this issue.

Appreciate all inputs and thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are using core data and you have changed database schema in the new version, it could be the problem.

Comment: Hi @rv7284 - thanks for reply. Actually we dont have core data in old app, but we have squlite database only. And then we have added few tables in it and that's it. There is no other changes we did in database.

Comment: that might be the issue, make sure that you have done database migration properly.

Comment: OK that i will check and i have doubt is that i have storyboard with more than 40 screens combined of iphone and ipad. And might be case that will take much more time than expected.

Comment: if that was the case, you would have faced it in the previous version too.

Comment: No - i haven't faced this issues in previous version, so i think storyboard load is not the issue. There is something else which stops it to move further.

Comment: @rv7284 - Did you get any clue for this ?

Comment: sorry mate, no clue whatsoever. If you could share your project, I'll take a peek.

Comment: Actually i was able to fix that one by removing some piece of code from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions because if launch screen will take time more than 2-3 seconds then it will crash the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know its little delayed but i got answer myself. Let me answer here, so others get solution if they have same issue.

If Launch screen (Splash Screen) will take time more than 2-3 seconds, then app will get crash. And why it takes more time because if we write more logic in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**, then it will take more time than ideal time.

So you can increase the time limit of splash screen by writing following code in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**.

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{
   [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
}
```

I have set here my time limit to 5 seconds as of my requirement to show splash of 5 seconds. And it solved my issue. Hope this will for your. ***Cheers - KPCoding :)***